# Server sent events / SSE in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am tryin to use Server sent events in NestJs as per:
[here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events)

However when tryint to import

```
import { Sse } from '@nestjs/common';
```

I get:

*Module '"../../../../node_modules/@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'Sse'.ts(2305)*

nest info tells me:

```
[System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v12.11.1
NPM Version    : 6.11.3

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 6.14.2

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 6.11.11
passport version         : 6.2.0
graphql version          : 6.6.2
typeorm version          : 6.3.4
common version           : 6.11.11
core version             : 6.11.11
jwt version              : 6.1.2
```

Answer (score 3):

This solved the issue:

Nest CLI Version : 6.14.2
does NOT support SSE;

Upgrade to version:  7.5.2  +